# Snowflake - How to Call Stored Procedure in SSRS with multi-value parameter

Tags: stored-procedures, ssrs-expression, ssrs-2019

I have a Snowflake Stored Procedure written in Snowflake that has 3 dynamic parameters, 1. StartDate, 2. EndDate, 3. FromVQ (Multi-value parameter meaning users can select more than one value) that im embedding in ssrs stored procedure expression.

Error: Session variable $START does not exist

```
SET "Start" = TO_DATE(CURRENT_DATE-1); SET "End" = TO_DATE(CURRENT_DATE-1); SET "FromVQ"= 'VQ_OPT_Rx_CustSrvc_Core,VQ_OPT_Rx_CustSrvc_Core_Onshore'; CALL CDW_PRD_RX_DB.CDW_CCOPS_RPT_SC.USP_CALL_DETAILS_AGENT($Start,$End,$FromVQ);
```

2. When I hard code the parameter values it works but for the FromVQ parameter it does not recognize multiple values. I'm getting blank results

   CALL CDW_PRD_RX_DB.CDW_CCOPS_RPT_SC.USP_CALL_DETAILS_AGENT('2023-07-11','2023-07-12','VQ_OPT_Rx_CustSrvc_Core,,VQ_OPT_Rx_CustSrvc_Core_Onshore');